# Modificar una cadena de texto (string) para sumarle uno a su valor

Tags: c#, string, int

Tengo una `lista` de tipo `string`.

```
List<string> ultimaLista = null;
```

Donde guardo la ultima posición de otra lista que tengo que es un `string` con letras y números.

```
if(ultimaLista != null && ultimaLista.Count > 0)
{
    string primerValor = ultimaLista[0];
    int valorNum = int.Parse(primerValor);
    valorNum++;
    ultimaLista[0] = valorNum.ToString();
}
```

Como puedo aumentarle el contador a una cadena de texto sí ahí me aparece como `MSCSP11030` y para que sea `MSCSP11031`, intente con ese código pero me da un error que dice

> System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato
> correcto.'

En la variable `valorNum` al momento de string a número.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Luis podrías decirme si la respuesta te resultó útil, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ultimaLista != null && ultimaLista.Count > 0)
{
    string primerValor = ultimaLista[0];
    string sNum = primerValor.Substring(5);
    int valorNum = int.Parse(sNum);
    valorNum++;
    string nuevo = primerValor.Substring(0, 5);
    nuevo += valorNum.ToString();       
}
```

Utilizas la **función Substring** para copiar la parte numérica, posteriormente parseas a **int**, incrementas en **1** esta parte numérica, luego vuelves a usar la **función Substring** para copiar la parte no numérica, y entonces usas la **variable nuevo** para concatenar la parte de las letras, con la parte numérica ya incrementada, finalmente este nuevo valor se guarda en la **variable nuevo**.

Comment: Disculpe por la demora, no tenía la pc a la mano. Gracias por tu ayuda.